# The python pyqt5 class references

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

In `panel.py` the class that references `buttonA` in class cannot be signaled.

But in the `panel2.py` reference `buttonA` class can be achieved
If you want to repeat the use of `buttonA` class in the `panel.py` class, how to deal with such a problem. Try to inherit `buttonA` class can only occur once `btnA1`

`buttonA.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QApplication

class ButtonA(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
    
    def createButton(self):
        self.btnA1 = QPushButton("btnA1", self)
        self.btnA1.pressed.connect(self.onbtnA1Pressed)
        self.btnA1.released.connect(self.onbtnA1Released)
        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(self.btnA1)
        return vbox

    def onbtnA1Pressed(self):
        self.btnA1.setText("btnA1 clicked")

    def onbtnA1Released(self):
        self.btnA1.setText("btnA1")
```

`panel.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QApplication
import sys, buttonA

class Panel(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def createPanel(self):
        a1 = buttonA.ButtonA()
        a2 = buttonA.ButtonA()
        v1 = a1.createButton()
        v2 = a2.createButton()
    
        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addLayout(v1)
        vbox.addLayout(v2)
        self.setLayout(vbox)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    p = Panel()
    p.createPanel()
    p.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

`panel2.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout
import buttonA, sys

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
w = QWidget()

a1 = buttonA.ButtonA()
a2 = buttonA.ButtonA()
v1 = a1.createButton()
v2 = a2.createButton()

vbox = QVBoxLayout()
vbox.addLayout(v1)
vbox.addLayout(v2)
w.setLayout(vbox)
w.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `panel.py`, in your `createPanel` function you have to use an instance, in this case `self`, when declaring instance variables.

This should work:

**panel.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QApplication
import sys, buttonA

class Panel(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def createPanel(self):
        self.a1 = buttonA.ButtonA()
        self.a2 = buttonA.ButtonA()
        self.v1 = self.a1.createButton()
        self.v2 = self.a2.createButton()

        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addLayout(self.v1)
        vbox.addLayout(self.v2)
        self.setLayout(vbox)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    p = Panel()
    p.createPanel()
    p.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Although this will fix the OPs code, it doesn't really explain why. The problem is that, in *panel.py*,  the `ButtonA` class connects the signals to its **own** slots. But the `createPanel` method allows the instances of `ButtonA` to be garbage-collected, which will then automatically *disconnect* those slots. In *panel2.py*, the instances of `ButtonA` are global variables, so they won't be garbage-collected until the script exits.